# Jquery function with two events using &&

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var scroll_start = 0;
  var startchange = $('#heroSection');
  var offset = startchange.offset();
  $(document).scroll(function () {
    scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scroll_start > offset.top) && ($!(window).width()<760){
      $('#myTopnav').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)');
    } else {
      $('#myTopnav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    }

  });
});
```

I'm trying to get this function to work only when there is a scroll event and the window is larger than 760px wide but can't seem to crack it.

Comment: Please provide some markup (html) as well.

Comment: There are typos, you need `if (scroll_start > offset.top && $(window).width() > 760)`

Comment: `$!` - maybe the typo.

Comment: Always check the error console...

Comment: There is a syntax error here: `$!(window).width()<760`

Comment: @Utkanos Thank you for the reminder.
I'm actually getting an error 
"ESLint terminated with error: Max connection attempts reached"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var scroll_start = 0;
    var startchange = $('#heroSection');
    var offset = startchange.offset();
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
        if ((scroll_start > offset.top) && window.width > 760) {
            $('#myTopnav').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)');
        } else {
            $('#myTopnav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
        }

    });
});
```

You missed a "(" here

```
if **(**(scroll_start > offset.top) && window.width > 760){
```

Comment: window.width() is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```js
$(function() {
  var scroll_start = 0;
  var startchange = $('#heroSection');
  var offset = startchange.offset();
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log(scroll_start, offset.top, $(window).width());
    if (scroll_start > offset.top && $(window).width() > 760) {
      $('#myTopnav').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)');
    } else {
      $('#myTopnav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.tall {
  height: 1024px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myTopnav">Nav</div>
<div id="heroSection" class="tall">
  Tall
</div>
```

Might be better to use the opposite: `$(window).width() > 760`

Comment: That did the trick, thank you!

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/10ndkyq9/1/)